# Bootstrap Grid Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My CSS isn't picking up my different columns. They are stacked on top of each other. I want each of them each to span 4 columns of the same row.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4" id="directionsPanel1">
    <h3 class="directions-discription" id="directions-info1"></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" id="directionsPanel2">
    <h3 class="directions-discription" id="directions-info2"></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" id="directionsPanel3">
    <h3 class="directions-discription" id="directions-info3"></h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you viewing them in a medium (md) size window? If it's smaller than medium size they will stack. That's how Bootstrap works. If you want it smaller, change your `col-md-4`s to `col-sm-4`.

Comment: No, I'm in a large browser @Tricky12

Comment: It works for me here http://jsfiddle.net/844Yv/ . Medium is 992px and greater, so I'd make sure you're viewing that width or greater. If that isn't the issue then you should make sure you included Bootstrap correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using floats to get them to span on the same row? <div class="col-md-4 pull-left"> Note the pull-left class added

Comment: @Tricky12 that's what I was thinking. What's strange is that I do pick up the changes in the container classes. I added bootstrap-responsive.css and bootstrap.css and also the min files of both. I'm sure it must be something with my configuration, not quite sure what it is though.

Comment: @user2954587 You also need the bootstrap.min.js file. http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: @user2954587 Is your browser view level more than 100%? And I assume you have the proper closing tags on the container and row divs?

Comment: markup looks good; I also tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/DV22T/ - make sure you are including the .css files as well as jquery.js added before bootstrap.js (and yes, as @Nathan said, make sure you have your closing tags for `.container` and `.row` )

Comment: @Tricky12 If I add a button to the JS fiddle it doesn't look like the ones on the bootstrap website. Which file is needed for that? http://jsfiddle.net/DV22T/2/

Comment: @user2954587 The submit query button looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about this using floats. You can apply the float which is the pull-left helper class to the div.col-md-4 and then they won't stack upon each other.

Updated JS fiddle but you shouldn't need to float left in the CSS, couldn't get JS fiddle to pull bootstrap stuff.  http://jsfiddle.net/4xEPr/7/

```
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4 pull-left" id="directionsPanel1">
    <h3 class="directions-discription" id="directions-info1"></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 pull-left" id="directionsPanel2">
    <h3 class="directions-discription" id="directions-info2"></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 pull-left" id="directionsPanel3">
    <h3 class="directions-discription" id="directions-info3"></h3>
  </div>
```

AND CSS

```
    div.col-md-4 {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;;
```

}

Comment: In bootstrap, the `col-xx-x` classes add a "float" to the element, preventing the need for adding it yourself. You aren't wrong, but you add unnecessary code.

Comment: He wants the DIVs in a row not stacked so wouldn't you use floats? See my JSFiddle.